# Switch Statement using a loop in Java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

I have a switch statement to change image resourceId:

```
int imageId = 0;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            imageId = R.drawable.image0;
            break;
        case 1:
            imageId = R.drawable.image1;
            break;
        case 2:
            imageId = R.drawable.image2;
            break;
        case 3:
            imageId = R.drawable.image3;
            break;
        case 4:
            imageId = R.drawable.image4;
            break;
        case 5:
            imageId = R.drawable.image5;
            break;
        case 6:
            imageId = R.drawable.image6;
            break;
        case 7:
            imageId = R.drawable.image7;
            break;
    }
```

But I have been trying to find out how to do this using a loop, since the case number and the number at the end of each image matches.
Tried with a for loop but without success.

Can anyone help?

Thx!!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why do you need a loop? In any case surely `R.drawable` should just contain an `image[]` array? No loop or `switch` statement required.

Answer (score 6):

Why not give R.drawable an *array* of images and then you can do the below ?

```
imageId = R.drawable.images[i];
```

Here's [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Alternatives include a `java.util.List` of some particular implementation e.g. an `ArrayList`

Comment: How do you do that?
(Im new to Android)

Comment: I would check out that tutorial linked above

Answer (score 0):

hey why you not do like this, its simple and easy for beginner,
like we make click on onclicklistener,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.rlfeatured:
        // perform any action
        break;

    case R.id.rlbrowse:

     // perform any action
        break;
    case R.id.rlmyshows:

        break;
    case R.id.rlcategories:

        break;
    case R.id.rlfavourites:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you see above, thats what I have done and it works great bu I was wondering how to get something more efficient and without the need to specify each image resource

Comment: its a simple and efficient way to do like this, so just chill, it will not create any such problem, otherwise you need if else conditions.. but if you make click or doing something with image then you need to specify resource otherwise you can for loop and other conditions.. thanks